# Unwanted Stylesheet behaviour in Firefox

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

Please have a look at the following Kendo UI Dojo

http://dojo.telerik.com/@geeforceone/IkiCO

[image]

It renders the following html in Firefox. "right" should be also placed in the header, but it's not. It works fine in IE11 and Chrome.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're telling the object to flow right, but your 'left' is not floating. Because of this the box seems to break. If you add a float:left; to the 'left' div it will result in the proper position of the div

http://dojo.telerik.com/ImUsA